# Get original file extension and content type

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have a file Name that is `Test.txt`. Now if I change the extension of that file to `.xls`.

Now my file name is `Test.xls` instead of `Test.txt`.

Then how can I know the original file type of that file?

Comment: why is your filename tset ?

Comment: *Then how can I know the file type of that file.* it still contains plain text, so it's a text file? The fact Excel might be able to open it by interpreting it as CSV and extract data as such doesn't really matter. Please clarify your question: Why is this tagged WPF and what do you want to do with the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is no way to retrieve the previous extension or content type from a file.

You can try to parse the file (for example PDF documents start with `%PDF`), but that isn't a real solution in my opinion, since you need to know the format of each and every file format.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. You don't.

Slightly longer answer: You might be able to determine the format by interrogating the file content. Many formats have known header bytes at the start. It all depends on what formats you want.